# The Picker not visible in the view hierarchy warming

Tags: swiftui, picker

I tried to make a Picker in swiftui with below code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddUserUIView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var type = 1
    let types = ["type1", "type2"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker("The type is", selection: $type) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< types.count) {
                            Text("\(self.types[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Add user")
        }
    }
}
```

This UIView is in sheet and I pass core data context into it so that it can be save in it. But it print a warming if I change the Picker value.

> [TableView] Warning once only: 
>     UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). 
>     This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), 
>   and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes.

Comment: Is this a warning only or something does not work?

Comment: The Picker then can not work.

Comment: Confirm warning, once, in Console with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4, but Picker works properly - can be changed many times in one session, and after sheet reopened as well.

Comment: Is it mean the Picker not work as expected? Or there is alternative way to remove this warming report?

Comment: No, it works as expected.